# Performance testing with Vaadin application

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to record events for Vaadin application using Loadrunner web protocol. However, when I replay the recorded script, the request that goes in is different from what is being recorded. I am not sure on what basis these values change and I am not getting expected results/response due to the change in request. I am new to Vaadin app, any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have experience with Loadrunner but please checkout these tutorials. https://vaadin.com/blog/author/anastasia-smirnova

Comment: Related to what @SimonMartinelli mentioned, there is Gatling based load testing example included in Bakery demo project on Vaadin.com page https://bakery-flow.demo.vaadin.com/login, see description https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/starters/bakeryflow/overview/#full-stack-architecture